# Google Chrome extension: method from background window called from popup window not executing sometimes

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, google-api

I'm developing an extension that keeps it's authentication and authorization logic in **persistent** background script. Every ~30 mins token gets refreshed successfully. After same intervals of extension being idle, when user opens popup - `isAuthorizedToGSheet` does not return value. No errors in both background and popup debug console and no requests logged in Network tab.

I inserted `console.warn` call to check if it executes anything, but no thing was logged to console. I does not print the message, but warnings as depicted on screenshot below appear when triggering this function by opening popup. According to simplified `index.tsx` below it displays only loading bar.

After clicking outside (and closing the popup), everything works fine when relaunching and the bug is not reproducible for another half an hour. How to debug this issue? Is it possible that some error in execution of GAPI calls prevents `console.warn` to print into console, even if it's executed before any GAPI logic?

```
-------------
index.tsx
-------------
renderLoadingBar();
if (await authContext.isAuthorizedToGSheet(sid)) {
  renderStuff();
} else {
  renderUnauthorizedPage();
}

-------------
background.ts
-------------

(window as any).backgroundAuthContext = new AuthContext();

function tokenRefresh() {
  logger.verbose("refreshing tokens");
  (window as any).backgroundTokenService.authenticate()
    .then(() => logger.verbose("Token refreshed"))
    .catch(logger.error);
}

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(tokenRefresh);
chrome.alarms.create("tokenRefresh", {periodInMinutes: 30});
tokenRefresh();

--------------
AuthContext.ts
--------------

export class AuthContext {
public async isAuthorizedToGSheet(sid: string): Promise<boolean> {
    console.warn("start auth");
    ...authorization logic using GAPI
  }
}

function getBackgroundAuthContext(): Promise<AuthContext> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(backgroundPage => {
      resolve(((backgroundPage as any).backgroundAuthContext as AuthContext));
    });
  });
}

export const authContext = {
  isAuthorizedToGSheet: (sid: string) => getBackgroundAuthContext()
    .then(backgroundAuthContext => backgroundAuthContext.isAuthorizedToGSheet(sid)).catch(console.error),
};
```

[image: Warnings after calling isAuthorizedToGSheet]

Comment: Since you're using a persistent background page you can access it *synchronously* via chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for quick response.
`export const authContext = {
  isAuthorizedToGSheet: (sid: string) => (chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() as any).backgroundAuthContext.isAuthorizedToGSheet(sid),
};`
Changed like this. Same result.